# Mongo DB query count and grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for the equivalent mongo db query for this tsql query.

```
select instructor, count(instructor)
from test
group by instructor
```

I have looked at mongo db documentation but nothing I run seems to work.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      instructor: "",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I get an error saying test is not an accumulator.

My desired output would be something like so.

instructor count
a    1
b    7
c    23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `$group` stage, you need the `_id` which is the group key. For the fields other than `_id`, it must be an accumulator which using the [accumulator operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator).

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$instructor",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      test: "$_id",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

---

For the update that why the query is not workable for Post Owner, it is due to `instructor` field was within `section_listing` array/object.

1. `$set` - Create `instructors` field.

   1.1. For the document which has the `section_listing` field as an array, removes the duplicate `instructor` with `$setUnion`.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `instructors` array to multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `instructors` and perform the count.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      instructors: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$section_listing.instructor"
              },
              "array"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$section_listing.instructor"
            ]
          },
          else: "$section_listing.instructor"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$instructors"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$instructors",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      instructor: "$_id",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/alfEdwx0SBY)

Comment: Thanks for Yong Shun. This seems to only count the documents in my collection and not the count of instructors within the documents. I have updated my question if that makes things different?

Comment: The group by will result the output of the number of documents by **each** instructor. Is it the result you want?

Comment: Ideally the output I would like is the name of each instructor and the count they appear in the documents.

Comment: I see, I believe the above query is what you need. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hu36aAnu1Dj)

Comment: I can see it works in the playground but it doesn't seem to work in the shell

this is what gets returned.
{ count: 2112, instructor: '' }

Comment: Perhaps can you share the sample document in the MongoPlaayground link?

Comment: Here you go :) https://mongoplayground.net/p/pPbWqXuJ-F-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247382/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-jacko).